# Why is the "Normal Vector" normal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I was trying to understand why the unit normal vector is normal to the direction of motion. Note that $\mathbf T(t) = \frac{\mathbf r'(t)}{||\mathbf r'(t)||}$ is the unit tangent vector for some vector valued function $\mathbf r(t)$, and the unit normal vector is defined to be $\mathbf N(t) = \frac{\mathbf T'(t)}{||\mathbf T'(t)||}$My book offered the following proof:

> To prove that $\mathbf T(t)$ and $\mathbf T'(t)$ are orthogonal, note that $\mathbf T(t)$ is a unit vector, so $\mathbf T(t) \bullet \mathbf T(t) = 1$.

//this is because $\mathbf u 
\bullet \mathbf v = (||\mathbf u||$ $  ||\mathbf v|| ) cos\theta$

> $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf T(t)\bullet\mathbf T(t) = 2\mathbf T(t)\bullet\mathbf T'(t) = 0$
>
> This shows that $\mathbf T(t)\bullet\mathbf T'(t) = 0$

That's all well and good, and I understand WHY that proves that $\mathbf N(t)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf T(t)$, but now I'm extremely confused because I can use the same proof to show that $\mathbf T(t)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf r(t)$.

> $\mathbf r(t) \bullet \mathbf r(t) = c$
>
> $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf r(t)\bullet\mathbf r(t) = 2\mathbf r(t)\bullet\mathbf r'(t) = 0$

What am I missing?

Comment: The last derivation of yours is well-known in physics. It is called centripetal motion.

Comment: @Nameless But $\mathbf T(t)$ should be tangent to $\mathbf r(t)$, and if it was orthogonal, then that would mean that $\mathbf N(t)$ is actually tangent... but it is supposed to be normal... I'm so confused

Comment: $\mathbf T(t)$ *is* tangent to the curve $\mathbf r(t)$, but it is *normal* to the vector $\mathbf r(t)$ itself when $\Vert \mathbf r(t) \Vert$ is constant. See my answer below.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis OH! Thank you for noting the difference between the vector and the curve. That, along with your answer, really cleared it up.

Comment: Glad to help out!  Ho-Ho-Ho---Ha-Ha-Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much what is being *missed* here, as it is what is being *assumed* . . .

The assertion that

$\mathbf r(t) \cdot \mathbf r(t) = c \tag{1}$

only holds under the condition that $\Vert r(t) \Vert = \sqrt{c}$ is a constant, i.e., the curve lies in a sphere of radius $\sqrt{c}$ centered at the origin.  In this case,

$\mathbf r(t) \cdot \mathbf r'(t) = 0 \tag{2}$

follows and makes perfect sense:  every tangent vector to a sphere is normal to its radial vector.  For a general curve,

$\mathbf r(t) \cdot \mathbf r(t) = c(t) \tag{3}$

where $c(t)$ is a time-varying *function*.  Then (2) will not hold though we still have

$\mathbf T(t) \cdot \mathbf T'(t) = 0, \tag{4}$

since

$\mathbf T(t) \cdot \mathbf T(t) = 1, \tag{5}$

where $\mathbf T(t) = \mathbf r(t) / \Vert \mathbf r(t) \Vert$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

And as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***